# Recursively sum a list and compare it to a key in python

Tags: python, recursion

I need to write a recursive function sums_to(nums, k) that takes a list of integers and returns True if the sum of all the elements in the list is equal to k and returns False otherwise.

I can't use sum function in any form, nor sum the list and then at the end check whether it equals k. In addition, I have to  write sums_to as a single recursive function.

So far I have this:

```
def sums_to(nums, k):
    if nums == []:
        if k == 0
            return True
        return 0
    else:
        return nums[0] + sums_to(nums[1:], k) == k
```

Comment: I've made an effort to fix your indentation, which appeared to have pasted into the question wrong - please confirm that what I've done does match what you intended.

Answer (score 3):

Your approach doesn't seem correct, in particular the recursive step isn't right - you have to decrease the expected `k` value until we reach the end of the list (and only test `k` at this point!), instead of adding/comparing at each point of the list. Also, the base case is missing something - what happens if `k` *is not* zero? you should return `False`, not `0`. Better try this:

```
def sums_to(nums, k):
    if nums == []:
        return k == 0
    else:
        return sums_to(nums[1:], k - nums[0])
```

It works as expected:

```
sums_to([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 14)
=> False
sums_to([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 16)
=> False
sums_to([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 15)
=> True
```

Comment: could you add how to do this for 3 numbers?

Comment: @DataTx What do you mean? post sample input and expected output.